# Query filter over ForeignKey in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi

To simplify, I have two tables (ORM FastAPI)

```
class Object(Base):
    __tablename__ = "object"
    id = Column('id', Integer, Identity(start=1), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(VARCHAR2(30), unique=True, index=True)
    attributes = relationship("Attributes", backref="parent", cascade="all, delete", passive_deletes=True)
    
class Attributes(Base):
    __tablename__ = "attributes"    
    id = Column('id', Integer, Identity(start=1), primary_key=True)
    attribute = Column(VARCHAR2(200), index=True)
    value = Column(VARCHAR2(2000), index=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("object.id",ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
```

An object can have multiple attributes, (1-N relationship).
Attributes are dynamic (depending of the object, some objects have 10 attributes, or 50...)

For example:

```
Object      | Attributes
---------------------------------
Object 1    | color = red
            | form = round
            | level = 5
            | ...
            | attribute alpha
---------------------------------
Object 2    | color = red
            | form = square
            | level = 2
            | ...
            | attribute beta
```

I would like to do something like :

*"find all Objects where attribute.color = red and attribute.level >= 2 and attribute.X is defined"*

I tried :

```
query = db.query(Object).options( 
 joinedload(Attributes,innerjoin=False)).join(Attributes)
query = query.filter(Attributes.attribute == 'color')
query = query.filter(Attributes.value == 'red')
...
return query.all()
```

But I don't know how to cascade filters on table Attributes..

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement filters, i would use the [`any()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any):

```
query = (
    session.query(Object)
    # -- NOTE: below join is not needed for the filter part;
    # .options(joinedload(Attributes, innerjoin=False))
    # .join(Attributes)
    # add additional criteria
    .filter(
        Object.attributes.any(
            and_(
                Attributes.attribute == "color",
                Attributes.value == "red",
            )
        )
    )
    .filter(
        Object.attributes.any(
            and_(
                Attributes.attribute == "level",
                func.cast(Attributes.value, Integer) >= 2,
            )
        )
    )
    .filter(Object.attributes.any(Attributes.attribute == "X"))  # exists
)
```

which will produce SQL statement (exact one depends on the DB engine):

```
SELECT object.id,
       object.name
FROM object
WHERE (EXISTS
         (SELECT 1
          FROM attributes
          WHERE object.id = attributes.parent_id
            AND attributes.attribute = 'color'
            AND attributes.value = 'red'))
  AND (EXISTS
         (SELECT 1
          FROM attributes
          WHERE object.id = attributes.parent_id
            AND attributes.attribute = 'level'
            AND CAST(attributes.value AS INTEGER) >= 2))
  AND (EXISTS
         (SELECT 1
          FROM attributes
          WHERE object.id = attributes.parent_id
            AND attributes.attribute = 'X'))
```